# Joomla article link #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla, hyperlink, article

im having a problem with all the articles i create. I cannot get a full article to open. when i click on the link it gives me this error. 
When i remove the title which is after the colon the link works. How do i fix this?

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':fauzi-halabi-seizes-kampionato-di-korsou-bola-9' at line 1 SQL=SELECT title FROM qbf2v_content WHERE id=29:fauzi-halabi-seizes-kampionato-di-korsou-bola-9
```

Joomla 3.4.1
Server version: 5.5.40-36.1-log

Comment: Is it possible to provide the query that is generating this error?

Comment: Turn on debug to get the queries but also you need to explain a lot more, such as what plugins you have installed and what you mean by "cannot get a full article to open." Open in an editor? Or render as a page? Site or administrator? You need to provide information and talk about what you have tried (i.e. disabling plugins)

Answer (score 0):

The id that is stored in database in your case is `29` so you have to separate it from id slug you got from query string `id=29:fauzi-halabi-seizes-kampionato-di-korsou-bola-9`.

This should help you.

```
$input_id = explode(":", $id);
$id = $input_id[0];
```

Reference: [The Slug](https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component#The_Slug)

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling SEF urls (and url rewriting using .htaccess if you are using apache server) in global configuration.